# Android distance bar/radius

Tags: android, distance, radius

I am working on an app where you can set a radius but I can't get it to work the way I want. I have been told that the way I want is a iOS thing. Can someone please confirm that?

[Link to short clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik0oqs3uy0nwq17/point%202.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

May you can use one of these libs:

https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar

https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

https://github.com/bq/MarkerSeekBar